# regex: how match []something|[]some?

Tags: regex

I'm trying write a regex which can match this

> []something|some|...

so basically needs match words and/or array characters [] and match any number of options/types (could be 2 or many more)

I try this

```
(\[?\]?\w+\||\|\[?\]?\w+)
```

but this fails because if it match the `|` character with the first regex can't comeback for match the `|` character in the beginning of the second option `|\|\[?\]?\w+`

i would like capture only the types in expressions like this

```
function blah(a: []something|[]some|blah)
```

match only

```
1) []something
2) []some
3) blah
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, please read the [tour] (it's not long). Please take a look at [Using Markdown to format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make your question more readable.

Comment: How do you define an option?

Comment: Good question, I like how you included an attempted [tag:regex]. Nice of you to try, not many people do.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match strings like `[]something|some|another` and `something|some|option|op`

```
(\[\])?\w+(\|(\[\])?\w+)*
```

Basically we are looking for optional `[]` at the start. But they need to both be there or both be absent (that's why they're in a group `(...)`).
Then we have at least one word character followed by zero or more pipe symbols followed by a word (e.g. `|some`, `|option`, `|a`).

Note that the escaping of the characters may depend on the regex syntax of your favourite regex language. You may need to escape the group using `\(` and `\)` and/or may need to unquote the pipe character `|`. In some languages this symbol represents an *or* relation when unquoted but I'm. The same goes for `[]`. It may help if you specified the language you or syntax you are using.

If things are unclear, simply ask for clarification.

Comment: thank so much but it captures other words too, I've update my question I didnt clear about it, also I'd prefer capture []some instead of separe in [] and some, thanks!

Comment: Please include some lines you *don't* want matched in your question, thank you. -- It should now match multiple `[]...|[]...`